# htaccess redirect with www and path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I can't get my head around redirects in htaccess. I want that www and the path is always kept.
For example if I go to *example.com/de* I want it to redirect to *[www.example.com/en](http://www.example.com/en)* but at the moment it always redirects to the root *example.com* without the subpage.
Here's what I use currently in the htaccess:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE:**
I think now I know why it always redirect to root and not the subpage:

```
# If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php.
# For httpd.conf, you need to prefix each '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' with '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]
```

That was a default setting of the CMS I use. I just have no idea how to handle it. If I comment it out the whole page doesn't work.

Comment: keep your `R=301` rule above CMS handling rule and test in a new browser.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to redirect on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) use this .htacess and if you are not using a subdomain for your website

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```